# Applying a formula and then autofill the data till last visible cell in the column: VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I use this code to apply a length formula and then `Autofill` till the last visible cell but getting an error

> Runtime Error '1004'- Method 'Range' of object_Global' failed

**Code**

```
Range("C2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=LEN(RC[-1])"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C2:C" & Lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
Selection.Copy
```

Comment: If you are not really looking for Special cells, you use a 1 liner like `Range("C2:C" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).FormulaR1C1 = "=LEN(RC[-1])"`

Answer (score 1):

As always it's better to stay away from `Select`, `ActiveCell` and `Selection`.

Try the code below:

```
Dim FitRng As Range, Lastrow As Long

Range("C2").FormulaR1C1 = "=LEN(RC[-1])"

Set FitRng = Range("C2:C" & Lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
FitRng.FillDown
```

If you don't want to use the `FillDown` method, you can simply use:

```
FitRng.FormulaR1C1 = "=LEN(RC[-1])"
```

Comment: don't you also need to define `Lastrow`??

Comment: @nightcrawler23  I only corrected the part the PO has shared

Comment: I ran the original code and it gave error only because of the variable not defined, which mean that was the original problem. Optimizing the code wasn't the issue

Comment: @nightcrawler23 of course, also you don;t have in the PO code where he is setting ia `AutoFilter` and other settings, maybe different worksheets. I try to give the best answer to the section and information the PO has provided. (maybe he defined `Lastrow` as Double, how can I guess about all the information he hasn't provided ? )

Answer (score 1):

from your code it seems you want the length of cells in COl B. The below code works for me.

```
Sub x()
    Range("C2:C" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).FormulaR1C1 = "=LEN(RC[-1])"
End Sub
```